# Google Geocoding API Bug?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have run into a curious issue with the Google Geocoding API.  I am currently using it to find the latitude and longitude of addresses in Luxembourg.  I accidentally discovered that even if I got the post code and the country wrong in my API request I still get back the correct location and formatted address.

For instance

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1+route+d%27Arlon%2C8399+Windhof%2CLuxembourg&key={Your-API-Key}&language=fr
```

which is correct finds a hit, as expected.  However,

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1+route+d%27Arlon%2C83992+Windhof%2CGermany&key={Your-API-Key}&language=fr
```

too finds a hit, albeit with a `partial_match = true` being returned.

> To understand the issue without having to scroll & read that code - the API returns the "right" address even when you supply wrong details for country, postcode etc.

How this can be anything other than a bug I cannot imagine. However, initially, I had simply assumed that I would check for such issues by asking the user to check the supplied address if `partial_match` was found to be present.

However, just checking for this throws up false positives.  Take the URL

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2+route+d%27Arlon%2C8552+Oberpallen%2CLuxembourg&key={Your-API-Key}&language=fr
```

returns `2 Route d'Arlon, 8552 Oberpallen, Luxembourg` which - as far as I can tell - is precisely the same address as I supplied but the Geocoding API **STILL** returns `partial_match`.

Clearly, there is more to `partial_match` than immediately meets the eye.  I can certainly start instituting even more stringent checks on the returned result rather than simply relying on `partial_match`.  However, I am hoping that someone here might be able to shed light on two issues here

- Why is it that my third example above returns `partial_match` when all is apparently OK?
- Why on earth is the API returning anything other than an error status when I willfully supply it with the wrong country and zip code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I doubt that my question is going to find an answer here since the bug I have apparently found pertains to a rather "obscure" global location.  Along the way I have learnt something valuable which I felt I might as well share here rather than just close the question:

The fact of the matter is that when dealing with addresses across multiple national markets which the user enters and which you then check against the Google geo-coding API it is quite simply too risky to rely on any raw input from the user being reliable in any way.  Depending on where you are in the world there are so many different ways of entering an address

`house no, street, zip code, place, country` OR
`street house no,zip code place, country` OR
`street, house no, place, zip code, country` OR

.... .

Best practice would be to

- Secure the different address components - even the `house no + street` bit as distinct fields from the user
- On the server build up the entire address string as you like it - the geocoding API is more than capable of dealing with minor nuances such as `post code before place`, `post code after place`, `missing commas`, `too many commas` etc.
- If the API returns a `status = OK` don't rely on either the `formatted_address` or `partial_result` fields in any way.  Instead, rebuild the entire address in your chosen format using the `address_components` part of the result.
- Perform a string insensitive comparison of the address you sent out to the API and the address that you have just built.
- Only proceed to accept the address if you get a perfect match.

Be aware that the order of address components in address_components may vary so look specifically for components with the types[0] entry set to `street_number, route, locality, postal_code` and `country`.  Finally, spaces can wreck havoc with the best of schemes so before you compare anything do a

```
trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $str));
```

to ensure that you have gotten rid of all unwanted spaces.